# Apologize for the incovenience

Tags: word-usage

I have to write a formal (but not too formal)  email to my colleague. I've sent to him a document with the wrong format and  he asked me to make some changes on it.  I would like to say something similar to the following sentence that I found  :

> I have made the adjustment and apologize for the  inconvenience for any inconvenience this may have caused you.

Can I use  just "for the inconvenience" without "this may have caused you" like the following , without specify "the consequence"

> I have made the adjustment that you requested and apologize for the inconvenience. Please find attached a new updated version of the document.

Comment: Though you might consider that this phrase is used so often nowadays that it almost becomes meaningless (as far as whether you are really sorry or not).

Comment: Right up there with _We are experiencing higher than normal call volumes_ and _Your message is important to us._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most widely used (but somewhat informal) form of words is probably

> ... apologize for the inconvenience.

If you want to be completely formal and add **this may have caused you**, it is normal to replace **the** by **any**, like this:

> It is unusual for this type of error to arise and we apologize for **any** inconvenience this may have caused you. - [300_ successful business letters](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=Hu5UELIyBggC&pg=PA41&dq=%22for%20any%20inconvenience%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU6NjZg8vOAhWFuhoKHcAiCzcQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22for%20any%20inconvenience%22&f=false)